# Node Request inside request with cookie

Tags: node.js, node-request

I am using node request `var request = require(“request”);` in my config node to do a POST request and in response get a Cookie which need to be referred in all rest of requests.

I tried enabling COOKIE JAR that works fine if i chain my request under first request but I want to call rest of requests like GetList from custom node.

I tried toughcookie (file cookie) not working when i add `var j = request.jar(new FileCookieStore(‘cookies.json’))`;
  node stop working with no error.

Below is my config node, code using which I am getting Cookie.

```
function myAuthNode(n) {

        RED.nodes.createNode(this,n);
        this.username=n.username;
        this.password=n.password;


            this.connect=function(){
                //TODO-NG need to make URL configurable
                request.post({url: "http://localhost:8080/api/method/login", qs: {usr: this.username, pwd: this.password}}, function(err, res, body) {

                    if(err) {
                            return console.error(err);
                    }

                    console.log("HERE IF I PUT REQUEST Works fine");
                    console.log("CAN WE PASS ANOTHER REQUEST here from calling SOURCE to execute here?");

                });

        };



    }
```

Here in this custom node I am calling

```
 // The main node definition - most things happen in here
    function GetListNode(n) {
        // Create a RED node
        RED.nodes.createNode(this,n);
        console.log('I am called');

        //using auth config now you are connected, tell me what is needed?
        this.authConfig=RED.nodes.getNode(n.auth);
        //connect to config and do auth

        this.authConfig.connect();

//THIS ALWAYS FAILS due to cookie not found where as I enable request JAR

       request.get({url: "http://localhost:8080/api/resource/Project"}, function(err, res, body) {

                if(err) {
                        return console.error(err);
                }

                    console.log("Response body:", body);

            });


    }
```

Please suggest how to handle cookie in request so that all requests after auth works fine?

Can we pass a request definition to another request for execution inside it or how Cookie can be handled ?

Comment: Create single cookie jar instance and pass it round or set default: `var j = request.jar(); var request = request.defaults({jar:j})`. Also you could try to print out the content of cookie jar, `j.getCookieString(url);`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Risto. I tried that earlier in myAuthNode which show me my cookie but how to use it inside GetListNode while doing another request that is also same request object where I set defaults but it never read that jar what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you verify on the server side also that the request is not sending any of the cookie headers, just `console.log` or intercept the request with proxy to see the headers.

Comment: Also, you can simply attach cookies as string to headers. A bit more manually, but still it should work.

Comment: i don't want to do manually. So Jar is the first choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by doing below inside GetListNode(), i shifted second request inside the call:

```
this.authConfig.connect(function(){request.get({url: "http://localhost:8080/api/resource/Project"}, function(err, res, body) {

        if(err) {
                return console.error(err);
        }

            console.log("Response body:", body);

    });});
```

and inside config node i did below, added a function parameter and called that passed function, WORKED fine :):

```
this.connect=function(f){
                //TODO-NG need to make URL configurable
                request.post({url: "http://localhost:8080/api/method/login", qs: {usr: this.username, pwd: this.password}}, function(err, res, body) {

                    if(err) {
                            return console.error(err);
                    }

                     f.call();

                });

        };
```